# Intelligent downscaling for inline images

Tags: org-mode, images

I'd like to achieve the following intelligent scaling of inline images:

**If** `image-actual-width` > 800: scale it down to 800

**Else:** display image without any further scaling

Doing `(setq org-image-actual-width 800)` achieves the first part, but for smaller images it scales them up to 800, which I want to avoid.

I'd like to have this as a sane default - I know I can set buffer and image specific widths via attributes.